# Eclipse debugging not working properly with ART runtime

Tags: android, eclipse, dalvik

When using the ART runtime on my HTC One GPE with Eclipse the currently executing line of code indicator does not move when Step Over and Step Into are used. The execution appears to continue, but it is very hard to tell where it's at without the indicator. Switching back to Dalvik resolves the issue. Has anyone experienced this and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I think ART is presently a preview for system manufacturers and chipset makers.

Comment: I have the same problem too and also switched back to dalvik to make it start working

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same problem, switching back to Dalvik fixed the issue for me too
what made it hard to find is the fact that the debug was working rundomly sometimes on the first instructions dont know why

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the new VM as it shipped with kitkat has several bugs that affect debugging. In particular, stepping doesn't work at all well. There are numerous bug fixes already checked in to AOSP. I think this particular bug was fixed by this change, relatively innocuous though it sounds: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/f2910eef247b45ce1d489e323b36b5de6b6157aa

If you have a Nexus device you can build AOSP yourself and try it out. If not, you'll have to switch back to dalvik for now.

If you find other bugs, please use b.android.com to report them. You can't assume someone will make us aware of bug reports on stack overflow!